# Is there anyway to import a direction in C# without referring to its namespace every time?

Tags: c#

I have one project

```
namespace TestSetupParameters
{
    public class TestSetupParameters
    {
        public enum EDUToutputType
        {
            Analog,
            Digital
        }
    }
}
```

The next project references this via

```
using TS = TestSetupParameters.TestSetupParameters;
//...
TS.EDUToutputType output = TS.EDUToutputType.Analog;
```

IS there anyway to get rid of the "TS." by changing the "using TS = " line? -- Could do using `EanalogInterfaceType = TestSetupParameters.TestSetupParameters.EanalogInterfaceType;`, but that would have to be done for every single thing in the class.

I'm looking for something similar to Python's "from X import *"

```
from fibo import *
>>> fib(500)
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the enum to be inside the class or could you move it out into the namespace directly?

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the class.- Great. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the enum is defined within the class there's no way to avoid prefacing the enum with the class name (or an alias in your case).  You also are complicating things by [using the same name for a namespace and the containing class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).  If you change the namespace (one guideline is something like `{Company}.{Project}.{Library}`) and move the `enum` out of the class definition then you should be able to just do:

```
using {namespace}
```

and reference both the class and the enum without prefixes.

Comment: Great. I felt this was wrong doing ABC.ABC.xxxx all the time, but that article gave me some ideas on what to do instead